# Lifting automorphic Galois representations to arithmetic fundamental groups and their quotients

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, automorphic-forms, galois-representations

Suppose $V$ is an algebraic variety over a number field $K$. The absolute Galois group $G_K$ of $K$ acts by outer automorphisms on the étale fundamental group $\pi_1(V_{\bar{K}})$ where $\bar{K}$ is the algebraic closure of $K$.

This Galois action, call it $\phi$, gives rise to outer Galois actions on any quotient of $\pi_1(V_{\bar{K}})$ by a characteristic subgroup. In particular we get actions on its quotients by members of the derived series of $\pi_1(V_{\bar{K}})$ as well as its lower central series.

First member of these series is the commutator subgroup whose quotient is $H_1(V_{\bar{K}})$. The corresponding outer Galois action on this abelan quotient is in fact a linear representation $\phi_1$ of $G_K$ on $H_1(V_{\bar{K}})$. Associated, thus, with the outer action $\phi$ on $\pi_1(V_{\bar{K}})$ is a sequence of outer Galois actions on bigger and bigger quotients by successive members of the given series, $\phi_i: i = 1, 2, ...$, the first of which is linear.

Suppose the linear representation $\phi_1$ proves to be automorphic (after dualizing to cohomology and taking an appropriate $l$-adic realization, say.) How can we "lift" its automorphy up the series to actions $\phi_i$, all the way perhaps to $\phi$? To begin with, what kind of objects would correspond to the automorphic representation associated to $\phi_1$ in such a lift?

What light does Deligne's work on $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$-action on nilpotent completion of $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Q}} - \{0,1,\infty\})$ throw on this question?

Comment: The obvious first thing to do is to follow Deligne and look at the Galois action on the Lie algebra. But this is interesting for its non-semisimplicity, and extension classes do not factor into automorphy of Galois representations - Langlands parameters are semisimple, so we can only say a Galois representation is automorphic if its irreducible components are. So the main thing we care about are the irreducible components, whcih are all wedge powers of $H^1$. So at minimum, we can ask whether these wedge powers are automorphic - a special case of functoriality.

Comment: @ Will Sawin, so following Deligne, one can ask (1) first, as you say, if the wedge powers of $H^1$ appearing as irreducible constituents of the Lie algebras of the pro-$l$ parts of the nilpotent quotients of $\pi_1$ are automorphic, next (2) if they are, what that says about the nature of the mixed motives Deligne constructs for these Lie algebras (in his particular case), and finally (3) what that says about the outer Galois actions that these motives are associated with.

Comment: @Will Sawin, do you imagine this could imply existence of automorphic local systems on $V$ akin to Deligne’s Kloosterman sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^1 - \{0, \infty\}$ whose automorphy, for any split reductive group in fact, is shown in Heinloth, Ngô and Yun, _[Kloosterman sheaves for reductive group](http://math.mit.edu/~zyun/Kloosterman_published.pdf)_?